# Swift: Trunc a floating number to show it in a label

Tags: swift

When I wanted to trunc a floating number for showing in a label in Objective-C I could just use `LABEL.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.3f", FLOAT];`

Though I can't find how to do so in Swift.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The old NSString format is still available. You can use that.

```
let myfloat : Float = 1.23
LABEL.text = NSString(format: "%.3f", myfloat)
```